# Comparing two columns of a csv and outputting string similarity ratio in another csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv, difflib, sequencematcher

I am very new to python programming. I am trying to take a csv file that has two columns of string values and want to compare the similarity ratio of the string between both columns. Then I want to take the values and output the ratio in another file.

The csv may look like this:

```
Column 1|Column 2 
tomato|tomatoe 
potato|potatao 
apple|appel
```

I want the output file to show for each row, how similar the string in Column 1 is to Column 2. I am using difflib to output the ratio score.

This is the code I have so far:

```
import csv
import difflib

f = open('test.csv')

csf_f = csv.reader(f)

row_a = []
row_b = []

for row in csf_f:
    row_a.append(row[0])
    row_b.append(row[1])

a = row_a
b = row_b

def similar(a, b):
    return difflib.SequenceMatcher(a, b).ratio()

match_ratio = similar(a, b)

match_list = []
for row in match_ratio:
    match_list.append(row)

with open("output.csv", "wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerows(match_list)

f.close()
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "comparison.py", line 24, in <module>
    for row in match_ratio:
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

I feel like I am not importing the column list correctly and running it against the sequencematcher function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another way to get this done using [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html):

> **Consider your csv data is like this:**

```
Column 1,Column 2 
tomato,tomatoe 
potato,potatao 
apple,appel
```

> **CODE**

```
import pandas as pd
import difflib as diff
#Read the CSV
df = pd.read_csv('datac.csv')
#Create a new column 'diff' and get the result of comparision to it
df['diff'] = df.apply(lambda x: diff.SequenceMatcher(None, x[0].strip(), x[1].strip()).ratio(), axis=1) 
#Save the dataframe to CSV and you could also save it in other formats like excel, html etc
df.to_csv('outdata.csv',index=False)
```

> **Result**

```
Column 1,Column 2 ,diff
tomato,tomatoe ,0.923076923077
potato,potatao ,0.923076923077
apple,appel ,0.8
```

Comment: This worked really well. I need to explore pandas some more. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The `for` loop you're setting up here expects something like an array where you have `match_ratio`, and judging by the error you're getting, that's not what you have. It looks like you're missing the first argument for `difflib.SequenceMatcher`, which should probably be `None`. See 6.3.1 here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html

Without that first argument specified, I think you're getting back `0.0` from `difflib.SequenceMatcher` and then trying to run `ratio` off of that. Even if you correct your `SequenceMatcher` call, I think you'll still be trying to iterate on a single float value that `ratio` is returning. I think you need to call `SequenceMatcher` inside the loop for each set of values you're comparing.

So you'd wind up with a call more like this in your function: `difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, a, b)`. Or if you'd prefer, since these are named arguments, you could do something like this: `difflib.SequenceMatcher(a=a, b=b)`.

Comment: I'll also add that renaming `row_a` and `row_b` to `a` and `b` halfway through is really confusing. It's easy to forget that you're dealing with two lists here, not two string values that you can compare.

Comment: Ah, that makes a lot of sense. I see what you are referring to.

Answer (score 1):

Your sample file looks like it contains markup tags. Assuming you are actually reading a CSV file, the error you are getting is because match_ratio is not an iterable datatype, it's a floating point number -- the return value of your function: similar(). In your code, the function call would have to be contained within a for loop to call it for each a, b string pair. Here's a working example I created that does away with the explicit for loops and uses a list comprehension instead:

```
import csv
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

path_in = 'csv1.csv'
path_out = 'csv2.csv'

with open(path_in, 'r') as csv_file_in:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file_in)
    col_headers = csv_reader.next()
    for row in csv_reader:
        results = [[row[0],
                    row[1],
                    SequenceMatcher(None, row[0], row[1]).ratio()]
                    for row in csv_reader]

with open(path_out, 'wb') as csv_file_out:
    col_headers.append('Ratio')
    out_rows = [col_headers] + results
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file_out, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerows(out_rows)
```

In addition to the error you received you might also have run into a problem when instantiating the SequenceMatcher object -- its first parameter wasn't specified in your code. You can find more on [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [SequenceMatcher](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#sequencematcher-objects) in the Python docs. Good luck in your future Python coding.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting that error because the records row[0] or row[1] contain most probably NaN values.
Try forcing them to string first by making str(row[0]) and str(row[1])

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because you are running SequenceMatcher on the list of strings, rather than on the strings themselves. When you do this, you get back a single float value, rather than the list of ration values I think you were expecting.

If I understand what you are trying to do, then you don't need to read in the rows first. You can simply find the diff ratio as you iterate through the rows.

```
import csv
import difflib

match_list = []
with open('test.csv') as f:
    csv_f = csv.reader(f)
    for row in csv_f:
        match_list.append([difflib.SequenceMatcher(a=row[0], b=row[1]).ratio()])

with open('output.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerows(match_list)
```

Comment: Wow, that is so much cleaner than what I have. I tried running this code and a sample csv file and produces this error:     writer.writerows(match_list)
_csv.Error: sequence expected

Comment: Sorry, I updated my post to fix this. writerows is expecting an iterable of iterables, but my solution was passing an iterable of floats.