# Apply string matching logic across all combinations of rows in csv file

Tags: python, arrays, string, pandas, csv

I am trying to work on string matching with python. I have .csv data like:

```
Item_ID»Item_Name
101»tomato
102»tomatos
103»tomatoes
104»tomato
```

(The `»`s represent tab `\t` characters.)

I want output to be like :

```
Item_ID»Item_ID1»Similarity
101»102»92
101»103»73
101»104»100
102»101»92
102»103»85
102»104»92
104»101»100
104»102»92
104»103»73
```

The `Item_Name` can be same but it has different ID, The similarity should be based on `Item_name` but to be calculated with each `Item_ID`. Can you help me with the python code for this?

Comment: That is just for an example. Sorry for not mentioning that.

Comment: Similarity should be based on the value of Item_name to Item_name.
Eg: "Tomato" (101) can be 92% similar to the string "Tomatoes" (102)

Comment: OK, but how are we meant to *calculate* the value 92%. If we cannot calculate the value, we cannot create a column containing that value. Please update the desired output to something that we can actually calculate through *some replicable logic*.

Comment: somewhat like this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36802453/comparing-two-columns-of-a-csv-and-outputting-string-similarity-ratio-in-another

Comment: So my solution below uses `difflib.SequenceMatcher`. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would implement your logic via `pandas`.

```
import pandas as pd
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
from io import StringIO
from itertools import combinations

mystr = StringIO("""Item_ID Item_Name
101 tomato
102 tomatos
103 tomatoes
104 tomato""")

# replace mystr with 'input.csv'
d = pd.read_csv(mystr, delim_whitespace=True).set_index('Item_ID')['Item_Name'].to_dict()

# create dictionary of results
d_out = {idx: [i, j, SequenceMatcher(None, d[i], d[j]).ratio()] \
              for idx, (i, j) in enumerate(combinations(d, 2))}

# create dataframe from dictionary
res = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d_out, orient='index')

# rename columns
res.columns = ['Item_ID', 'Item_ID1', 'Similarity']

# output to csv
res.to_csv('result.csv', index=False)
```

Result:

```
   Item_ID  Item_ID1  Similarity
0      101       102    0.923077
1      101       103    0.857143
2      101       104    1.000000
3      102       103    0.933333
4      102       104    0.923077
5      103       104    0.857143
```

Comment: Yes, But how can I add 104 in column 'Item_ID' I want identical rows too.

Comment: Replace the 2 instances of `combinations` with `permutations`. That should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the input into a `list` of `dict`s, as in my example.

Then, you can use `itertools.combinations(data, 2)` to get all the pairs.

```
import itertools
import random

def get_similarity(obj1, obj2):
    # your own get_similarity function using obj1['name'], obj2['id'], etc
    # here I'm just returning random number
    return random.randint(1, 100)

data = [
    {'id': 101, 'name': 'tomato'},
    {'id': 102, 'name': 'tomatos'},
    {'id': 103, 'name': 'tomatoes'},
    {'id': 104, 'name': 'tomato'},
]

print('Item_ID1', '\t', 'Item_ID2', '\t', 'Similarity')
for obj1, obj2 in itertools.combinations(data, 2):
    similarity = get_similarity(obj1, obj2)
    print(obj1['id'], '\t', obj2['id'], '\t', similarity)
```

This outputs

```
Item_ID1     Item_ID2    Similarity
101      102     89
101      103     83
101      104     75
102      103     9
102      104     3
103      104     86
```

In your sample output, you are repeating the same pair twice (for example, (101, 104) and (104, 101).

If this was intended, you can simply print the same pair twice with the order of objects swapped:

```
for obj1, obj2 in itertools.combinations(data, 2):
    similarity = get_similarity(obj1, obj2)
    print(obj1['id'], '\t', obj2['id'], '\t', similarity)
    print(obj2['id'], '\t', obj1['id'], '\t', similarity)
```

Comment: Thanks, Can it be done on .CSV file as well?

Comment: Also, is it creating random integer or is actually calculating string similarity with any algorithm?

Comment: @RishabOberoi Yes! You can do it by creating a list, constructing a `dict` with fields 'id' and 'name' for CSV each row, and push the `dict` into the list when you are reading the csv file. I think it would be a great exercise if you started learning Python. I just used random integers, but you should replace it with your similarity calculation logic.

Comment: Okay, Thanks for the help Eric. I will try this solution suggested by you.